# Add all products to a new category 2.4.4

Tags: database, magento2.4, products, category-products, category-tree

In my magento 2.4.4 version i just created a new category. I need to assign all products to this new category. So keep the product to their current category but in addition assign to this new one category. Is it possible through or in different way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess simplest way is run SQL to DB

**[Updated for CE compatibility]**

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO catalog_category_product
SELECT NULL, {CATEGORY_ID}, entity_id, 0 FROM catalog_product_entity;
```

Don't forget to replace placeholder `{CATEGORY_ID}` to your Category ID;

Comment: If he has a lot of products then doing this manually is not a good option.

Comment: I got following error: https://ibb.co/pPxTQ6D #1146 - table 'magento.sequence_product' not exists

Comment: @user3718303, please see updated answer, initially I've provided solution for Commerce version.

Comment: @MuhammadMuizAther Why? And what option you can suggest as alternative? This is best and faster way to add all products to category. P.S. Don't forget to run reindex after doing operation like this.

Comment: Thanks! your solution works very well!

Comment: Do you think is possible to run a cron job with this SQL query?

Comment: Possible, but if you want to add product to some category like Everything is better way to create plugin/observer on before save product and add category. Alternative is create modifier with default category for new products.

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk I think a cron job would be a better way of doing if they have more products. Otherwise your solution is good.